# Error focus not working reliably for conditionally rendered fields - React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In my react hook form component, I have a select component for selecting a payment option from one of two options: `Mpesa Buy Goods` and `Mpesa Paybill`. Both of these fields are rendered conditionally, so they're only displayed once the user selects one of either. Because of this, the conventional `RHF` `register` method alone doesn't work, so a custom ref is necessary.

When the user selects the first option (Mpesa Buy Goods), and its form fields are rendered, but attempts to submit the form without populating any of the fields, an error is displayed and the first field with an error receives focus, meaning it works as expected. And when they select the second option first (Mpesa Paybill) meaning they didn't select the first option at all, and the respective form fields are rendered, but attempt to submit the form without populating any of the fields, again, an error is displayed for all the form fields not populated and the first field receives focus, meaning that it works as expected too.

The problem is that when the user selects the first option first (Mpesa Buy Goods) and then maybe changes their mind and decides to select the second option instead (Mpesa Paybill), and then attempts to submit the form without populating any of the form fields, the errors are displayed as expected but the first form field with an error does not receive focus. This is inconsistent behavior across UI and not good for UX.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to implement an if block to check if the currently selected option is `Mpesa Paybill` using `selectedPaymentsMode` (state variable to track currently rendered mode of payment) and if the field exists in `formState.errors` when the user attempts to submit the form. If so, trigger validation with `trigger` with `shouldFocus` set to `true` and a similar approach for subsequent fields. This approach ins't working reliably.

**Code:**

**Mode of Payment:**

```
          <div>
            <h2>
              Mode of Payment
              <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
            </h2>
            <select
              {...register("modeOfPayment", {
                onChange: (e) => {
                  setSelectedPaymentMode(e.target.value);
                  handleModeOfPaymentChange(e);
                },
              })}
              className={`h-10 w-1/3 text-sm ${
                errors?.modeOfPayment?.message
                  ? "border-red-700 focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-700 focus:ring-2"
                  : "focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-emerald-700 focus:ring-2"
              }`}
            >
              <option value="" disabled={true}>
                Choose a mode of payment
              </option>
              <option>Mpesa Buy Goods</option>
              <option>Mpesa Paybill</option>
            </select>
            {errors?.modeOfPayment?.message && (
              <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                {errors.modeOfPayment.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
```

**handle mode of payment change:**

```
  const handleModeOfPaymentChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    setSelectedPaymentMode(e.target.value);
  };
```

**Mpesa Buy Goods (conditionally rendered):**

```
{selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods" && (
            <div>
              <h2>
                Enter till number
                <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
              </h2>
              <input
                {...restTillNumber}
                ref={(e) => {
                  tillNoRef(e);
                  tillNumberRef.current = e;
                }}
                type="text"
                className={`h-8 w-11/12 self-center text-sm ${
                  errors?.tillNumber?.message
                    ? "border-red-700 focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-700 focus:ring-2"
                    : "focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-emerald-700 focus:ring-2"
                }`}
              />
              {errors?.tillNumber?.message && (
                <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                  {errors.tillNumber.message}
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
```

**Mpesa Paybill (conditionally rendered):**

```
          {selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill" && (
            <div>
              <div>
                <h2>
                  Enter Paybill number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restPaybillNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    paybillNoRef(e);
                    paybillNumberRef.current = e;
                  }}
                  className={`h-8 w-11/12 self-center text-sm ${
                    errors?.paybillNumber?.message
                      ? "border-red-700 focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-700 focus:ring-2"
                      : "focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-emerald-700 focus:ring-2"
                  }`}
                />
                {errors?.paybillNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.paybillNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2>
                  Account number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restAccountNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    accountNoRef(e);
                    accountNumberRef.current = e;
                  }}
                  className={`h-8 w-11/12 self-center text-sm ${
                    errors?.accountNumber?.message
                      ? "border-red-700 focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-700 focus:ring-2"
                      : "focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-emerald-700 focus:ring-2"
                  }`}
                />
                {errors?.accountNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.accountNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
```

**track currently rendered option:**

```
  const [selectedPaymentMode, setSelectedPaymentMode] = useState("");

  const watchedPaybillNumber = watch("paybillNumber");
  const watchedAccountNumber = watch("accountNumber");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill" &&
      // formState.isSubmitSuccessful === false &&
      "paybillNumber" in formState.errors
    ) {
      console.log("error in paybillNumber!");
      trigger("paybillNumber", { shouldFocus: true });
      // setFocus("paybillNumber");
    }

  }, [watchedPaybillNumber]);
```

**refs for conditionally rendered form fields:**

```
  const tillNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const paybillNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const accountNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const { ref: tillNoRef, ...restTillNumber } = register("tillNumber");
  const { ref: paybillNoRef, ...restPaybillNumber } = register("paybillNumber");
  const { ref: accountNoRef, ...restAccountNumber } = register("accountNumber");
```

**FormSchema:**

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  tillNumber: z
    .string()
    .nonempty({ message: "Please provide a value" })
    .min(5, { message: "Please enter a valid till number" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid till number" }),
  paybillNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid paybill number" }),
  accountNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(20, { message: "Please enter a valid account number" }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `RHF` `reset` method which according to the docs, resets the entire form state, fields reference, and subscriptions.

Add it to the `useEffect` function with `selectedPaymentMode` as a dependency:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill") {
      reset({ tillNumber: "" }); // reset form
      clearErrors("tillNumber");
    }
    if (selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods") {
      reset({ paybillNumber: "", accountNumber: "" });
      clearErrors(["paybillNumber", "accountNumber"]);
    }
  }, [selectedPaymentMode]);
```